# How to concatenate formatted values in SAS

Tags: json, datatables, sas, format, datastep

I'm exporting data in JSON format with sas using this macro I made:

```
%macro json4datatables(ds,path,file,charvars,numvars)
    / store source
    DES="json4datatables(ds,path,file,charvars,numvars)";

    /* creates a json with no headers
     * a bit like a csv without the first line
     * it takes thus less space
     * but you have to know which column is what
     */

    data _null_;
        length line $300;
        set &ds nobs=nobs end=end;
        file "&path.&file." encoding='utf-8' bom/**/ ;

        line = '[';

        %if &charvars ne %then %do;
            %do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&charvars));
                %let charvar = %scan(&charvars, &i);
                %if &i ne 1 %then %do;
                    line = cats(line,',');
                %end;
                line = cats(line,'"',&charvar,'"');
            %end;
        %end;
        %if &numvars ne %then %do;
            %do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&numvars));
                %let numvar = %scan(&numvars, &i);
                %if &i ne 1 OR &charvars ne %then %do;
                    line = cats(line,',');
                %end;
                line = cats(line,'',&numvar,'');
            %end;
        %end;

        line = cats(line,']');

        if _n_=1 then put '{"data": [';
        if not end then put line +(-1) ',';
        else do;
            put line;
            put ']}';
        end;
    run;

%mend json4datatables;
```

but my problem is that raw values are exported.
I would like to export the formatted values.

How can I achieve this?
I'm thinking maybe there is a function that allows to concatenate formatted values instead of values and I could replace cats() with it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `VVALUE()` function.

```
line = cats(line,'',vvalue(&numvar),'');
```

Also why not just use the `CATX()` function?  Replace

```
%if &i ne 1 OR &charvars ne %then %do;
    line = cats(line,',');
%end;
line = cats(line,'',vvalue(&numvar),'');
```

with

```
line = catx(',',line,vvalue(&numvar));
```

For the character values use the `QUOTE()` function.

```
line = catx(',',line,quote(cats(vvalue(&charvar))));
```

Move the addition of the square brackets to the end.

```
line = cats('[',line,']');
```

Comment: Thanks! and I'm used to cats, it makes things more readable for me, but i'll try.

Comment: the catx replacements do not work, they add a comma in front of the first value `[,"BORPER","fatal_1","0.78"],`

Comment: Because the LINE variable was not empty.  You could build the comma separated values first and then add the square brackets later.

Answer (score 2):

VVALUE is probably the function you are looking for, but it would not replace CATS.  Also for quoting use QUOTE function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `put`, `putc` or `putn` function to print value with format, to obtain a format use `vformat function`, but when you are using `vformat function` only `putn` and `putc` support it.

```
line = cats(line,'"',putc(&charvar, vformat(&charvar)),'"');
line = cats(line,'',putn(&numvar, vformat(&numvar)),'');
```

Comment: The problem with using the `put` functions is that you need to know the format name.  Using `vvalue()` as the others suggested will take the format name applied to the column and use that instead.